# REST API - "GET /user" changes user in database

Tags: rest, api-design

We have a simple User API including "GET /user" to request user information. When processing the request we store the current datetime as "lastVisit" in our database. As a result we have a GET request updating the user in our database, which seems to be bad practice.

As we don't handle the login process on ourselves, GET /user is the first request to our backend. We cannot use /login to retrieve and store "lastVisit".

Is it bad practice? How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with updating your database when you receive a GET request - the uniform interface of HTTP constrains what the GET method token *means*, but you have a lot of freedom in how your server implements the handling of that request.

So that much is fine.

"lastVisit", however, may be a problem - which is to say, your interpretation of what it means that somebody asked for a copy of the page ignores various edge cases: a web spider following links to index the documents (think Google), or a smart browser that is trying to reduce latency by downloading a link before the user clicks on it.

You don't know, from the request, whether the fetch was triggered by the client, or by the general purpose agent acting in the client's stead.  Similarly, you don't know about any requests for the resource that were intercepted and handled by a cache that had a valid copy of the resource.

It *may* be that using request handling time as a proxy for last visit is a good enough cost effective approximation of what you want to get by, but you should keep in mind that it is an estimate, not a truth.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you are right, as long as we do not include "lastVisit" in our response, there is no problem with updating it via GET on our database. We adjusted our API accordingly.